# Hover text transition pushing down rows (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling to find the reason for my `col-sm-4` items to be pushed down during the transition.

There must be a conflict in a class property that is giving too much height to each box.

EDITED: the page has now changed. The issue was quite a common bug with Bootstrap 3 and wrapping elements, that caused the row to have a different height.

Comment: can you please provide your html and css only for those rows, at first glance I already see that you defining margin of your outer div with your inner div, this is semantically wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made it work properly. As I mentioned in the comment you didn't respect box model semantics and applied your `margin-bottom` to `.cat-post-container`, which is inner element of `.col-sm-4`. If you do it like this, it works:

```
.col-sm-4 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cat-post-container {
    // margin-bottom: 20px; *remove this rule*
}
```

Also, as your box is functioning like link, you should set you `.col-sm-4 a` to display block to cover the content area as a block container.

```
.col-sm-4 > a {
    display: block;
}
```